# Combination Sum

Tags: c++, recursion, combinations, backtracking

Given a set of candidate numbers (C) and a target number (T), find all unique combinations in C where the candidate numbers sums to T.

The same repeated number may be chosen from C unlimited number of times.

> ```
> All numbers (including target) will be positive integers.
> Elements in a combination (a1, a2, … , ak) must be in non-descending order. (ie, a1 ≤ a2 ≤ … ≤ ak).
> The combinations themselves must be sorted in ascending order.
> CombinationA > CombinationB iff (a1 > b1) OR (a1 = b1 AND a2 > b2) OR … (a1 = b1 AND a2 = b2 AND … ai = bi AND ai+1 > bi+1)
> The solution set must not contain duplicate combinations.
> ```

Example,
Given candidate set `2,3,6,7` and target `7`,
A solution set is:

`[2, 2, 3]
 [7]`

The solution code is :

```
class Solution {
    public:

    void doWork(vector<int> &candidates, int index, vector<int> &current, int currentSum, int target, vector<vector<int> > &ans) {
        if (currentSum > target) {
            return;
        }
        if (currentSum == target) {
            ans.push_back(current);
            return;
        }
        for (int i = index; i < candidates.size(); i++) {
            current.push_back(candidates[i]);
            currentSum += candidates[i];

            doWork(candidates, i, current, currentSum, target, ans);

            current.pop_back();
            currentSum -= candidates[i];
        }

    }

    vector<vector<int>> combinationSum(vector<int> &candidates, int target) {
        vector<int> current; 
        vector<vector<int> > ans;
        sort(candidates.begin(), candidates.end());
        vector<int> uniqueCandidates;
        for (int i = 0; i < candidates.size(); i++) {
            if (i == 0 || candidates[i] != candidates[i-1]) {
                uniqueCandidates.push_back(candidates[i]);
            }
        }
        doWork(uniqueCandidates, 0, current, 0, target, ans); 
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Now, while i can understand the solution by taking an example case, how can i myself come out with such a solution. The main work is going in this function :

```
    for (int i = index; i < candidates.size(); i++) {
        current.push_back(candidates[i]);
        currentSum += candidates[i];

        doWork(candidates, i, current, currentSum, target, ans);

        current.pop_back();
        currentSum -= candidates[i];
    }
```

Please tell me how to comprehend the above code and how to think that solution. I can solve basic recursion problems but these look out of reach. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why am I getting downvotes?

Comment: You are most likely receiving downvotes because people feel that you are asking others to do your work for you in stead of asking for help with something you have already tried to solve.

Comment: @MikelF I have given atleast 6 hours to this problem. I don't know what is the definition of "trying"?

Comment: Please understand that I am not saying that you are not trying to solve the problem. I am saying that the perception may be that you are asking others for free coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what the code basically does is:

1. Sort the given set of numbers in increasing order.
2. Remove duplicates from the set.
3. For each number in the set:

   - Keep adding the same number, until the sum is either larger or equal to the target.
   - If it is equal, save the combination.
   - If it is larger, remove the lastly added number (go back to the previous step) and start adding the next number in the set to the sum.

For understanding recursion, I like to start with very simple cases. Let's see for example:
`Candidates: { 2, 2, 1 }`
`Target: 4`

Sorting and removing the duplicates changes the set to { 1, 2 }. The sequence of recursion will be:

- Sum = 1;

  - Sum = 1 + 1;

    - Sum = 1 + 1 + 1;

      - Sum = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1; (Same as target, save the combination)
      - Sum = 1 + 1 + 1 + 2; (Larger than target, no more number to add)
    - Sum = 1 + 1 + 2; (Save the combination, no more number to add)
  - Sum = 1 + 2;

    - Sum = 1 + 2 + 2; (Larger, no more number)
- Sum = 2;

  - Sum = 2 + 2; (Save, this is the last recursion)

Comment: Thanks but can you also tell me how to come up with that recursive function. I mean what should be my thinking process step wise, sorry to be naive.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it now.